# Hibernate - OneToOne error

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I am trying to setup a OneToOne relationship on the following entities Event & Plan. The issue is that when I submit (which is a update) on event nothing goes into plan table (create for plan)

In the IDE I can inspect what comes back from browser and there is a value in Plan - although plan.id is null as plan is new.

The console shows an error that event_id is null (event_id is the FK on plan table).

**Event**

```
@Entity
public class Event {
@Id
private Long id;
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "event", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Plan plan;
//
```

**Plan**

```
@Entity
public class Plan {
@Id
private Long id;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false)
private Event event
//
```

I have a form which updates an existing Event and needs to create a Plan.

When I submit the form the following error is thrown:

**browser:**

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

**console**

```
""2017-05-16 19:16:34 - Column 'event_id' cannot be null
""2017-05-16 19:16:34 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'event_id' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

I understand that the basis of this error is that event_id (which is on table plan) can not be null - but the plan is submitted as part of a event update - so event_id shoud be obtained as a result of a correctly setup relationship?

**Event Service**

```
Event savedEvent = eventRepository.save(event); // this line ok
return eventRepository.save(event); // this line errors as above
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: Without seeing the data access code, it's impossible to tell why you have this problem.

Comment: The owner side is the side which doesn't have the mappedBy attribute. It's the one Hibernate cares about. You need to make sure to set the event of the plan: plan.setEvent(...).

Comment: The object that comes back from the browser is a event and it already has a plan object attached to it, with the some test data. Why do I need to set that relationship again?

Comment: Again, the problem is not that the event doesn't have a plan. The problem is that the plan doesn't have an event.

Comment: Would you be able to show me a code snippet? Because all the googling I have done shows this as being a correctly setup Bidirectional OneToOne?

Comment: Are you saying I should have a field named plan_id on event table?

Comment: No. I said that you must set the event of the plan, not only the plan of the event. `plan.setEvent(event)`. The problem is not that the bidirectional assicoation is incorrectly defined. The problem is that you're only initialize the inverse side of the association, and not the owning side. The plan of the event is set, but the event of the plan is not. This is inconsistent, and Hibernate only cares about the owning side that you're not setting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bidirectional relation, so basically what you need is each side of the relation to have reference to the other side, in your case you only have one reference.

To solve this you can either turn the relation to be unidirectional by removing the mapping from one side or inject the missing reference

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to have the plan_id recorded on the event table. So the annotations became:

**Event**

```
@Entity
public class Event {
@Id
private Long id;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Plan plan;
//
```

**Plan**

```
@Entity
public class Plan {
@Id
private Long id;
//
```

I actually never needed to make it Bidirectional (the solution above is Unidirectional).